# Print Array to table

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array with data and I have to put them into a table.
Array:

```
array(
 0=>1
 1=>Jon
 2=>jon@email.com
 3=>2
 4=>Doe
 5=>doe@email.com
 6=>3
 7=>Foo
 8=>foo@email.com)
```

So Table head is:

```
<table>
    <head>
       <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Email</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

If I go and loop through the array:

```
 <table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Email</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       @foreach($array as $data)
           <tr>
             <td>
               {{$data}}
             </td>
           </tr> 
       @endforeach
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Current Output:

```
Id   Name  Email
1   Jon  jon@email.com 2 Doe doe@email.com  3  Foo foo@email.com
```

But My desired output is:

```
Id   Name  Email
 1   Jon   jon@email.com
 2   Doe   doe@email.com
 3   Foo   foo@email.com
```

I tried to chunk array into arrays with array_chunk() but the result was the same.

I am on laravel but I can go with plain php also.
Any tips would be much apreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<tbody>
   @foreach(array_chunk($array, 3) as $data)
       <tr>
         <td>
           {{ $data[0] }}
         </td>
         <td>
           {{ $data[1] }}
         </td>
         <td>
           {{ $data[2] }}
         </td>
       </tr> 
   @endforeach
<tbody>
```

Comment: Didn't know about chunk method :)

Comment: This gives me undefined offset [0]

Comment: @Davis Try: `array_chunk($array, 3)` in the place of `collect($array)->chunk(3)`.

Comment: @SandOfVega Wow! This works. One more thing. I will never know how many <td></td> I will have so I would have to make it as dynamic as possible. Any tips on that?
So in other word it would have to count <td>`s itself

Comment: @Davis read: [HTML Tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp). This tutorial may help you.

Comment: @SandOfVega Thanks man! I made it all dynamic. Works like a charm!

Comment: @Davis You Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you.

```
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Email</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       @for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i= $i+3)
           <tr>
             <td>
               {{ $array[$i] }}
             </td>
             <td>
               {{ $array[$i + 1] }}
             </td>
             <td>
               {{ $array[$i + 2] }}
             </td>
           </tr> 
       @endforeach
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all no way your current code will give that output you're showing. It should be vertical, each element in its separate row. But let's fix the problem.

You don't have proper objects to work on so here condition is that after 3 iterations, new data is coming. So you can take mod of 3 and make it work like this:

```
@foreach ( $array as $key => $value )

// you have a new dataset
@if ( ($key % 3) == 0 )
<tr>
    @endif
<td>{{ $value }}</td>
@if ( ($key % 3) == 0 )
</tr>
    @endif

@endforeach
```

I have not tested this code above but it should work. Though I would always prefer to use proper List of objects of User class or something else.

EDIT: I would prefer @Sand Of Vega's answer. Its better.

Comment: The problem is that I cant have a proper object because the data has been sent to me over stored procedure and it returns array.
However this almoust works. Now it returns 
ID Name Email
1 joe@email.com
Joe
2Doe doe@email
Doe

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Re-place your  with following.

```
 <table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Email</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>   
        <tr>
           @foreach($array as $key => $value)
               if($key % 3 == 0){
                  echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
           @endforeach
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not so familiar with laravel butI hope following works for you.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      $length = (int) count($array)/3;
      @for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i+=3)
        <tr>
          <td>{{$data[$i]}}</td>
          <td>{{$data[$i+1]}}</td>
          <td>{{$data[$i+2]}}</td>
        </tr> 
       @endfor
    <tbody>
</table>
```